# Sorting orthogonal null space vectors

Tags: sorting

My program generates orthogonal null space vectors such as this:

`{{0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
  {0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
  {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0},
  {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0},
  {1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1},
  {0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0}}`.

My goal is to find the ordering which looks at the first occurrence of 1 within the vector. The desired ordering for the above is `{5,1,2,6,3,4}` corresponding to

`{{1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1},
  {0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, 
  {0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
  {0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0}, 
  {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0}, 
  {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0}}`

Primitive attempts using `Ordering` and `Sort` have failed; my hope is someone can save me from the faux pas of a `Do` loop.

Comment: Perhaps `Reverse[Ordering[vecs]]` ?

Comment: Yes, that's it as Martimer has shown. Thanks to you both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Ordering[{{0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
{0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0},
{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0},
{1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1},
{0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0}}]//Reverse

{5, 1, 2, 6, 3, 4}

{{0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
{0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0},
{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0},
{1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1},
{0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0}}[[{5,1,2,6,3,4}]]

{{1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1},
{0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
{0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
{0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0},
{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0},
{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0}}
```